# Response CSS container losing margin at tablet size only

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-selectors, margin, responsive

I've got the following CSS which is designed to resize to a certain number of columns at medium size, then full-width items at small/mobile size. Everything seems to work, except that at the medium/tablet size, margin-top (for example) on the outer container, with the .columnContainer class, is apparently discarded.

I've tried everything I can think of to figure this out, and have hit a brick wall. Thanks in advance for any help, and you can play with the CSS here: [**https://jsfiddle.net/xvLmhfpa/**](https://jsfiddle.net/xvLmhfpa/)

```
// This is getting stripped at medium size only!
.columnContainer { margin-top: 20px }

// Large size
@media all and ( min-width: 768px ) {

  .columnContainer { 
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .columnContainer > div { 
    display: table-cell;
  }

}

// Medium/tablet size
@media all and ( max-width: 767px ) and ( min-width: 481px ) {

  .columnContainer { 
     width: 100%;
  }

  .columnContainer > div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .columnContainer.collapse2 > div { width: 50%; }
  .columnContainer.collapse2 div:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }
  .columnContainer.collapse3 > div { width: 33.33%; }
  .columnContainer.collapse3 div:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: both; }
  .columnContainer.collapse4 > div { width: 25%; }
  .columnContainer.collapse4 div:nth-child(4n+1) { clear: both; }
  .columnContainer.collapse5 > div { width: 20%; }
  .columnContainer.collapse5 div:nth-child(5n+1) { clear: both; }
  .columnContainer.collapse6 > div { width: 20%; }
  .columnContainer.collapse6 div:nth-child(5n+1) { clear: both; }
}

// Small/mobile size
@media all and ( max-width: 480px ) {
  .columnContainer > div { width: 100% }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have `float:left` in your medium size..
Add `display:inline-block` in the div..

```
@media all and ( max-width: 767px ) and ( min-width: 481px ) {

.columnContainer { 
     width: 100%;
     display:inline-block;
  }

  .columnContainer > div {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvLmhfpa/2/)..